# Input field with dropdown and typeahead

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've looked online for a solution to this, but none of the solutions quite fits my need.

What I want is a control that contains a dropdown with values, which the user can choose to show and select a value from by pressing the typical arrow button in the field, and where typing something in the field also shows the dropdown and filters the values in it according the the input.

So in terms of angular-ui-bootstrap terminology, it's a `input/select`-element with `typeahead`.

For me this is how a normal dropdown field should work, but I can't find any implementation of this.

There are some implementations which shows the typehead popup when the field is focused, etc. But I feel that it would be weird for the user if the got a popup when they focus what appears to be a normal input field.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT2`  style. You can also select a value from by pressing the typical arrow button in the field, and where typing something in the field

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2({
      placeholder: 'Select an option'
    });
});
```

```css
select{
  width :200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
  <optgroup label="Alaskan/Hawaiian Time Zone" data-select2-id="171">
    <option value="AK" data-select2-id="172">Alaska</option>
    <option value="HI" data-select2-id="173">Hawaii</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Pacific Time Zone" data-select2-id="174">
    <option value="CA" data-select2-id="175">California</option>
    <option value="NV" data-select2-id="176">Nevada</option>
    <option value="OR" data-select2-id="177">Oregon</option>
    <option value="WA" data-select2-id="178">Washington</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone" data-select2-id="179">
    <option value="AZ" data-select2-id="180">Arizona</option>
    <option value="CO" data-select2-id="181">Colorado</option>
    <option value="ID" data-select2-id="182">Idaho</option>
    <option value="MT" data-select2-id="183">Montana</option>
    <option value="NE" data-select2-id="184">Nebraska</option>
    <option value="NM" data-select2-id="185">New Mexico</option>
    <option value="ND" data-select2-id="186">North Dakota</option>
    <option value="UT" data-select2-id="187">Utah</option>
    <option value="WY" data-select2-id="188">Wyoming</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Central Time Zone" data-select2-id="189">
    <option value="AL" data-select2-id="190">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AR" data-select2-id="191">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="IL" data-select2-id="192">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IA" data-select2-id="193">Iowa</option>
    <option value="KS" data-select2-id="194">Kansas</option>
    <option value="KY" data-select2-id="195">Kentucky</option>
    <option value="LA" data-select2-id="196">Louisiana</option>
    <option value="MN" data-select2-id="197">Minnesota</option>
    <option value="MS" data-select2-id="198">Mississippi</option>
    <option value="MO" data-select2-id="199">Missouri</option>
    <option value="OK" data-select2-id="200">Oklahoma</option>
    <option value="SD" data-select2-id="201">South Dakota</option>
    <option value="TX" data-select2-id="202">Texas</option>
    <option value="TN" data-select2-id="203">Tennessee</option>
    <option value="WI" data-select2-id="204">Wisconsin</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Eastern Time Zone" data-select2-id="205">
    <option value="CT" data-select2-id="206">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE" data-select2-id="207">Delaware</option>
    <option value="FL" data-select2-id="208">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA" data-select2-id="209">Georgia</option>
    <option value="IN" data-select2-id="210">Indiana</option>
    <option value="ME" data-select2-id="211">Maine</option>
    <option value="MD" data-select2-id="212">Maryland</option>
    <option value="MA" data-select2-id="213">Massachusetts</option>
    <option value="MI" data-select2-id="214">Michigan</option>
    <option value="NH" data-select2-id="215">New Hampshire</option>
    <option value="NJ" data-select2-id="216">New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY" data-select2-id="217">New York</option>
    <option value="NC" data-select2-id="218">North Carolina</option>
    <option value="OH" data-select2-id="219">Ohio</option>
    <option value="PA" data-select2-id="220">Pennsylvania</option>
    <option value="RI" data-select2-id="221">Rhode Island</option>
    <option value="SC" data-select2-id="222">South Carolina</option>
    <option value="VT" data-select2-id="223">Vermont</option>
    <option value="VA" data-select2-id="224">Virginia</option>
    <option value="WV" data-select2-id="225">West Virginia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

For more details please check [here](https://select2.org/)